# How do I get this matrix in Smith Normal Form? Every matrix in $M(\mathbb{Z})$ can be taked in Smith form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I take this matrix and try put in Smith Normal Form, but the numbers in diagonal not follow disivibility rules. So I make myself a question:

if every matrix has a Smith Normal Form, how to proceed when diagonal matrix not follow disivibility rules?

What is operation we can make to solve this?

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3  \\
    3 & 4 & 5  \\
    2 & 2 & 13
  \end{bmatrix}
this matrix belongs to $M(\mathbb{Z})$.

I hope be clear. And so thankfull for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smith normal form is 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&22\end{pmatrix}$$

The first step is to use row and column operations to reduce the first row and column, the result of that is 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-2&-4\\0&-2&11\end{pmatrix}$$
Now we can operate with the $2\times 2$ submatrix reduction giving 
$$\begin{pmatrix}-2&0\\0&11\end{pmatrix}$$
Next we have the row/column operations,
$$\begin{pmatrix}-2&11\\0&11\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}-2&1\\0&11\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\22&11\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\22&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus after some transpositions, the result above.

Comment: To expand on concern of OP if the 1 in top left of the second matrix had not been a 1 Rene could have used the Euclidean algorithm to ensure that it divided every element of the 2 by 2 submatrix in bottom right corner. This ensures you can always achieve required divisibility property.